# How do I get the text for a jquery flexigrid element that does not have an abbr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, flexigrid

I have a column that is a FK and so cannot have the ID value. Instead, I show a String value.  All well and good,except when I select a row and take an action, I need that value.

As you may know, flexigrid adds "abbr=" for sortable columns, but leaves them off for non-sorting columns.

I'm sure there is some jquery expression that will work.  I thought something like:

```
$('td:nth-child(4)', this).html()
```

Here is the HTML structure I am trying to navigate:
[image: JSP source]

Nothing I've tried works - just get syntax errors.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get this to work.  Here is the answer:

```
$('td:nth-child(4) >div', this).html();
```

This says: get the 4th td in the selection, then go to the div child; finally, get the html text for the child.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works as well:

```
$('td:nth-child(4)', this).text();
```